# where am I going wrong?

Tags: real-analysis

$(x_n)$ converge to $l$ means that:

$\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\ \exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\quad n\geq n_0\implies |x_n-l|\leq\epsilon $

so, we have for $n+1\geq n\geq n_0$:

$|x_{n+1}-l|\leq\epsilon/2\quad and\quad |x_n-l|\leq\epsilon/2 $.

$\implies |x_{n+1}-x_{n}|\leq \epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon\quad by\ the\ Triangle \ Inelquality$

$\implies $ $\forall n\geq n_0 \ x_{n+1}=x_n $

so, every convergent sequence stays contant for some interval.Is that correct ?I don't believe that this correct,because such a theorem dosen't exist!?

Comment: The last implication is false. What you've shown is that for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $n_0$ such that $$n \geq n_0 \Rightarrow | x_{n+1} - x_n | < \epsilon$$ That doesn't mean $x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$ are equal for all such $n$.

Comment: Note that $n_0$ depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: What David Mitra just said: $n_0$ is contingent on the $\epsilon$. If you could show (and we haven't that) that there exists the **same** $n_0$  that works for all $\epsilon$ where $E >\epsilon > 0$ (for some upper bound $E$), then yes.

Comment: No we don't. Perhaps this is easiest with a concrete example: $a_n = 1/n$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N = \lfloor 1/\epsilon \rfloor + 1$. Then $n \geq N \Rightarrow |a_n| < \epsilon$. So if $\epsilon = 1/10$, $N = 11$ works:
$$n \geq 11 = N \Rightarrow |a_n| = |1/n| < 1/10 = \epsilon$$

 But if $\epsilon = 1/100$, $N = 11$ definitely does not work.

Comment: Yes, the last statement you wrote is true with $|a|$. However with expressions involving the sequence, the logical statement with $a$ is in fact an expression contingent on $\epsilon$. Study the example I just wrote.

Comment: Yes ... and hence the choice of $n$ for which $|a_{n+1} - a_n| < \epsilon$ is true depends on $\epsilon$. The example sequence $a_n = 1/n$ also demonstrates this.

Comment: Look, your logic is clearly false as with $a_n = 1/n$, as it is not the case that for any $n$ we have $a_{n+1} = a_n$, because if that were true, then $1/(n+1) = 1/n$ or $n + 1 = n$ or $0 = 1$. So either you are misinterpreting the logic of the situation or there's something wrong with the logic. The first scenario is the correct one. I recommend one last time you study your logic with the example of $a_n = 1/n$. I'm afraid I'm going to have to leave it at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you showed in the argument (up to the last line):

$$\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}: \exists n_0 \in\mathbb{N}\, \forall n\in \mathbb{N} n \ge n_0 \Rightarrow |x_{n+1} - x_n| \le \varepsilon$$

This means that the distances between consecutive terms gets as small as we like.

But different $\varepsilon$ will have different $n_0$ (they will get larger and larger for smaller $\varepsilon$). So the final conclusion fails, as we never have that $\varepsilon = 0$...

Comment: but I'm still confused because we know that if $\forall\epsilon>0 \ |a|<\epsilon\implies\ a=0$

Comment: Sure, but we only know this from a certain index onwards, not for *all* $n$

Comment: And the index shifts away to infinity

Comment: Yes. Consider $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: No, you can't. Study the obvious counter example